# Google OAuth2 is not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

So recently I came across a problem, which is happening when i try to authenticate using google oauth2 from mobile, but when i try to authenticate via computer, it works fine. I am using it with passportjs in node/express project.

project link: https://rhubarb-tart-18821.herokuapp.com/

You guys can see code here:
https://ide.c9.io/saijax/www

just whole authentication is so big that i can not put everything here...

**EDIT:**

here are some main files

passport.js

```
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth2")
.Strategy;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const keys = require("./keys");
module.exports = (passport) => {
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
          clientID: keys.googleClientID,
          clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
          callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
          proxy: true 
    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    const image = profile.photos[0].value.substring(0, profile.photos[0].value.indexOf("?"));

    const newUser = {
        googleID: profile.id,
        email: profile.emails[0].value,
        firstName: profile.name.givenName,
        lastName: profile.name.familyName,
        image: image
    }
    // CHECK FOR USER
    User.findOne({
        googleID: profile.id
    }).then(user => {
        if(user){
            done(null, user);
        } else {
        // CREATE USER
            new User(newUser)
                .save()
                .then(user => done(null,user));
        }
    })
    })
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id)
        .then(user => done(null, user));
});
```

}

auth.js

```
const express = require("express");
const passport = require("passport");
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/google", passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: [
    "profile", 
    "email"
    ]
}));
router.get("/google/callback", passport.authenticate("google", {
    failureRedirect: "/"
}), (req, res) => {
    req.flash("success_msg", "Successfully Logged In");
    res.redirect("/dashboard");
});
router.get("/verify", (req, res) => {
    if(req.user){
        console.log(req.user);
    } else {
        console.log("Not auth");
    }
});
router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    req.flash("success_msg", "Successfully Logged Out");
    res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
// SETUP
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const session = require("express-session");
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const methodOverride = require("method-override");
const flash = require("connect-flash");

// LOAD GOOGLE AND MONGO KEYS
const keys = require("./config/keys");

// LOAD MODELS
require("./models/story");
require("./models/user");

// PASSPORT CONFIG 
require("./config/passport")(passport);

// LOAD ROUTES
const auth = require("./routes/auth");
const index = require("./routes/index");
const stories = require("./routes/stories");

// HANLEBARS HELPERS
const {
  truncate,
  stripTags,
  formatDate,
  select,
  editIcon
} = require("./helpers/hbs");

// MONGOOSE CONNECT
mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("MongoDB Connected...");
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));

// USE APP
const app = express();

// CSS CONFIG
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

// VIEW ENGINE
app.engine("handlebars", exphbs({
  helpers: {
    truncate: truncate,
    stripTags: stripTags,
    formatDate: formatDate,
    select: select,
    editIcon: editIcon
  },
  defaultLayout: "main"
}));
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");

// BODY PARSER
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// METHOD OVERRIDE
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

// FLASH
app.use(flash());

// COOKIE PARSER
app.use(cookieParser());

// SESSION MIDDLEWARE
app.use(session({
  secret: "KAPPA",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

// PASSPORT MIDDLEWARE
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// SET GLOBAL VARS
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash("success_msg");
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash("error_msg");
  next();
});

// ROUTES
app.use("/", index);
app.use("/auth", auth);
app.use("/stories", stories);
```

Comment: You don't have to put all of the code here, but you can at least copy here the relevant things (like express route configuration, maybe the passport strategy), and add the steps that you use on desktop that work, but do not work on mobile, and on which step you fail. Also, any error messages (or lack thereof), executed api endpoints on one then on the other case, similar things. You will more likely receive helpful answers if you help us help you.

Comment: @Zlatko thanks for replay, okay ill try to post code here, just thing is that i get literally 0 error when i try authentication from my computer, but i get only one from which is saying that my credentials are incorrect, but they are correct, i checked it million times.

Comment: Additionally, your Cloud 9 link asks for authentication. Many people do not have accounts and a lot won't open one just for one question on SO. As said, external links should be sparsely used, and the bulk of the problem (almost all needed to reconstruct the problem), should be in your question.

Comment: Okay thanks, currently working on it

Comment: I see much more info, pretty helpful. Although, I don't get anything from your link even on desktop, I get authentication flow, then I land back on your page with an 503 error: `An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. ` I think this 503 is from Heroku, saying your app crashed somewhere along the way. Check your heroku logs and see what they mean here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes

Comment: Can you try wrapping the entire contents of the google auth strategy in a try/catch for me? (the inner function, starting just above the `const image...` line and ending just bellow the `User.findOne().then` chain? See if you get errors in there, or somewhere inside the then blocks (won't be shown in this try/catch I think, but that is the next step.)

Comment: Also, this is now much more detailed question, looks a bit easier to reason about, to try to help.

Comment: @Zlatko hm, thing that you got 503 error is interesting, because i can access it from my pc and laptop... without any error, currently checking out logs for heroku, and there are no errors or warning, only stuff which shows me that i went on path for ex "/", on host="example.com" and this kind of stuff  Also, i tried to wrap  from const image to user.findOne(), but it gave me no error, right now i am trying to catch some errors on .then blocks and ill post what will happen! thanks for help

Comment: Well, weird, I don't get 503 any more. Maybe I was testing as you were deploying new code.

Comment: Also, I can log in from my iPhone (using Chrome, at least).

Comment: Maybe you can dump all your heroku logs and hang them somewhere? (when having large files like long logs, it is acceptable not to paste them here but use something like pastebin or similar).

Comment: Yeah, maybe thats why, one min ago i also updated it, i was getting one error, which i cought from one missed .catch(irony), but i still can not authenticate from mobile..

Comment: I'll try that as well, but right now i just found one thing that it might be just only heroku problem, because when i tried to go on my page via c9 url, it worked from both mobile and desktop. weird

Comment: UPDATE: well, i dont know if it was silly mistake or not, but it seems like mobile can not read `callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback"`, instead i changed following line with `callbackURL: keys.callback + "/auth/google/callback"` where keys.callback is url for my app(from c9/heroku) ... now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: well, i dont know if it was silly mistake or not, but it seems like mobile can not read

`callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback"`

instead i changed following line with

`callbackURL: keys.callback + "/auth/google/callback"`

where keys.callback is url for my app(from c9/heroku) ... now it works perfectly!